# How to compute the general term formula for the number of full binary tree heaps that can be formed with distinct elements?

Tags: combinatorics, recursion, heaps, priority-queues, generating-functions

The number of possible heaps that are full binary trees of height $h$ and can be formed with ($n = 2^h - 1$) distinct elements can be computed by recursion:
$$ a_h = {2^h - 2 \choose 2^{h - 1} - 1} a_{h - 1}^2 $$
How to compute the general term formula with this recursion formula?